# Isomorphism of the product space into the whol space : kernel and range of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

i am not sure how to proceed about the following exercise.

Let $E$ be a normed vectorial space. Let $p$ be a projection of $E$ (i.e $p \circ  p=p) $.
Show that the application from $ F \times G$ into $E$ where $F=Ker(p)$ and
$G=range(p)$ such that ,$u(x,y)=x+y$ is an isomorphism.

We proved just before that $F,G$ are closed in $E$.

Not sure about what i should use, the fact that $E$ and $F,G$ are in direct sum ? Should i work with $(p(u(x,y))$ ?
Thanks!

Comment: If you know that $F$ and $G$ sum directly to $E$, then you should use this. Indeed, $u : F \times G \to E : (x, y) \mapsto x + y$ is an isomorphism if and only if $F \oplus G = E$ (so you shouldn't need to use any other pieces of information).

Comment: I think i can use that fact in this exercise because the point of it is to show that if $p$ is continuous then $u$ is an isomorphism and then the reciprocal.